# How to understand confusion matrix and classification_report correctly

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I know that this question is somehow duplicated, but none of the answers I have seen clearly address my concerns so I would like to ask again about the confusion matrix and `classification_report` specific to my case here.

In general, I have used a Random Forest classifier to predict if a user returns to my web page or with 1 = 'Return' and 0 = 'No return'

1. After training and predicting the data, I had run some evaluation metrics as follows:

```
print('Precision score: {:.2f}'.format(precision_score(y_test, y_pred)))
print('Recall_score score: {:.2f}'.format(recall_score(y_test, y_pred)))
print('AUC.ROC score: {:.2f}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)))
```

> Precision score: 0.63
> Recall_score score: 0.16
> AUC.ROC score: 0.56

At this point, my understanding is that the result represents the 'Return' (value = 1) point of view, such that `recall = 0.16` means percentage of returning users are correctly identified.

> > So my first question is: Is my understanding so far correct?

2. I calculated the confusion matrix and `classification_report` to confirm the above result:

`print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))`

> `[[99981    3250]`
>
> `[28799    5447]]`

From this confusion matrix output, calculating Precision and Recall returned different value (0.97 and 0.78, respectively).

For `classification_report`:

`print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))`

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.78      0.97      0.86    103231
           1       0.63      0.16      0.25     34246
```

From the classification report, my assumption is that my understanding of question (1) was correct and the confusion matrix result above represents 'No return' users.

> > So my 2nd question: Is my conclusion above correct? If yes, then why is the confusion matrix returning values for 'No return' users instead of 'Return', and how I can I calculate a similar confusion matrix for 'Return' users?

Comment: In the confusion matrix you got all that you need, there is no CM for class 0 and another for 1. For example to compute the recall of class 0 what you do is: 99981/(99981+3250) and for the class 1: 5447/(28799+5447).

Comment: yes there is not cm for the classes but using the cm you can compute i.g the recall, precision, acuracy etc.. for your classes.